# Native Messaging extension in firefox not working

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, chrome-native-messaging

I am testing native messaging in Firefox extensions using the example at https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/main/native-messaging.

I have the `add-on` directory copied into a `~/extensions` directory on my machine, and I have copied the `app` directory into the `~/.mozzila/native-messaging-hosts` directory and changed the path in `ping_pong.json` to point to the new path of `ping_pong.py`. Performing `./ping_pong.py` from within this directory will successfully run the native application.

However, running the extension as a temporary add-on causes the error of:
`AbortError: Native application start canceled by user NativeMessaging.sys.mjs:178` and `NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE: Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsINativeMessagingPortal.closeSession]` in the browser console.

My version of Firefox is 122.0, and is ran from `/usr/bin/firefox`. I am on Ubuntu 23.04. Any idea on what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: I think the issue is the shebang link. Ubuntu doesn't have a `/usr/bin/python`. Use `#!/usr/bin/env python3` on the shebang and the example should work.